# After Updating to MySQL 5.6.9, localhost does not work anymore

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, apache2

I have installed Apache2 2.2.22, MySQL 5.5, and PHP 5.3 on my server. I am using codeigniter to do our project. Everything is working fine until I upgraded MySQL to 5.6, the developer release version. It shows ERROR2002(HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) and can no longer connect to my localhost. So, I downgraded back to 5.5 but still cannot connect to my localhost. It is showing HTTP ERROR 500 when I go to localhost.

I would remove and reinstall everything but would like to get a suggestion first. 
Thanks.

Comment: Try specifying 127.0.0.1 instead.

Comment: Can you connect to your mysql server using the same credentials as codeigniter using mysql commnand line, or other tools?

Comment: Yes, I can remotely connect to mysql

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and dropped back from 5.6 and everything worked fine. I am running PHP 5.5.1 and Apache 2.4. I would love to know how to get 5.6 working properly, but the only answer I have for now is to remove it. I left an earlier version installed which would not work either with codeigniter (worked with MySQLAdmin, MySQLyog) until MySQL 5.6 was uninstalled. As soon as 5.6 was gone the earlier version of MySQL worked fine again.